# Formula or function to change part of a text string color not using conditional formating

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a shape I am using to highlight text. The text is using a formula to get a set of text from the spreadsheet . I need a single word to be a different color than the rest of the text string. Since this a shape, conditional formation is grayed out.

How would I do this?

Comment: You could do it through VBA but it would have to break the link to do it. You'd setup a trigger to run every time the source cell changed. I don't know of any way to do it without VBA.

Comment: What have you researched or attempted so far?

Comment: As @EngineerToast mentioned, you can't modify partial text color with a worksheet formula